# Missing Expression

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT  count(*), idstagiaire  
FROM  absence  
natural join stagiaire  
where idfliere=2 AND typeabcense='nojustifie'
AND GROUP By idstagiaire;
```

I get error:

> Missing expression

```
stagiaire(idstagiaire,nom,prenom,idfliere,totalabsence)
Filiere(idfliere,nomfiliere)
module(idmodule,nommodule,nbrmodule)
fil_module(idfliere,idmodule)
absence(idabsence,dateabence,idstagiaire,idmodule,typeabcense)
```

Comment: Remove the dangling AND before group by.

Comment: You've got an unnecessary AND before GROUP by

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT  count(*),idstagiaire  FROM absence natural join stagiaire  where 
idfliere=2 AND typeabcense='nojustifie'
GROUP By idstagiaire;
```

Answer (score 1):

remove the last `and`:

```
SELECT  count(*),idstagiaire  
FROM  absence  natural join stagiaire  
where idfliere=2 AND typeabcense='nojustifie'
GROUP By idstagiaire;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT  count(*),idstagiaire 
 FROM  absence  natural join stagiaire  where idfliere=2 ANDtypeabcense='nojustifie'
 AND------------------------------->  Remove this AND   
 GROUP By idstagiaire;
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove 2nd '**AND**' from query

```
SELECT  count(*), idstagiaire  
FROM  absence  
natural join stagiaire  
where idfliere=2 AND typeabcense='nojustifie'
GROUP By idstagiaire;
```

Answer (score 0):

in below code

```
AND GROUP By idstagiaire;
```

AND is error, remove AND before of group by, if you want to add another condition then add it after AND,
for example

```
AND 'YOUR NEW CONDIOTION HERE' GROUP By idstagiaire;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try without the last **AND**.

```
SELECT  count(*), idstagiaire  
FROM  absence  
natural join stagiaire  
where idfliere=2 AND typeabcense='nojustifie'
GROUP By idstagiaire;
```